# AdColony causing IDFA related error

Tags: ios, app-store, ads, adcolony

I get the following error message when I try to upload the archived app to the App Store:

[image]

I tried removing AdColony I was able to upload. Any ideas on how to get this error fixed?

Answer (score 0):

We have throughly tested the app submission process and have found that apps submitted containing our SDK are being processed successfully through Apple’s iTunes Connect site.  Our SDK is fully compliant with Apple’s stated intended usage and collection requirements for IDFA.

When you are submitting your app, that contains our SDK, through iTunes Connect you MUST check all 4 of the boxes asking about IDFA.  Please see our support documentation on this issue here: http://support.adcolony.com/customer/portal/articles/1516610-device-identifiers-user-privacy.

We did have some reports from developers who were using other monetization partner's SDKs finding that one of these additional SDKs was causing the rejection.  You should check with any other monetization partners that you are working with to ensure that their SDKs are up to date and not the cause of what you are seeing.